# Select date between mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, date

I need to select records that are between 2 dates like follow:

```
select pa_EntryDate , pa_Number , pa_Value , pa_Note 
from payments 
where (DATE_FORMAT(pa_EntryDate, '%d/%m/%Y') 
between '1/6/2016' and '12/6/2016') 
and  pa_To = 42 
and archived=0
```

The date format in pa_EntryDate column is: "2015-09-10 00:00:00" ..

The results that generated are out of my dates range with some misses:

```
   pa_EntryDate      id      value
2015-09-10 00:00:00 1356    1031.00 
2015-11-12 00:00:00 1564    1111.00 
2015-12-10 00:00:00 1644    1138.00 
2016-02-11 00:00:00 192     1255.00 
2016-03-10 00:00:00 282     1110.00 
2016-05-12 00:00:00 467     1141.00
```

Comment: Show your code. Do you really have two constants to search between or do you have DateTime variables?

Comment: select pa_EntryDate , pa_Number , pa_Value , pa_Note from payments where DATE_FORMAT(pa_EntryDate, '%d-%m-%Y') between '" + txbFrom.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' and '" + txbTo.Value.ToShortDateString() + "' and  pa_To = " + sup_Id+" and archived=0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert you date str

```
select pa_EntryDate , pa_Number , pa_Value , pa_Note 
from payments 
where pa_EntryDate  between STR_TO_DATE('1/6/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') 
                   and STR_TO_DATE('12/6/2016', '%d/%m/%Y') 
and  pa_To = 42 
and archived=0;
```

Comment: In your query you convert the format of the date but not convert in string .. in  my query i convert the string in date so the date can be properly evalueted in between condition .. i hope this i clear